# Why does the compiler complain "incompatible types" for my generic function parameter?

Tags: delphi, generics, parameter-passing, delphi-2009

I am having problems with generics. I do not know how to pass `OnCallbackWrapper` to the `CallbackWrapper` procedure. I am getting 'incompatible types' error on the following example:

```
unit uTest;

interface

uses
  Generics.Defaults;

type
  TGenericCallback<T> = procedure(Fields: T);

type
  TSpecificFields = record
    A: Integer;
    B: Integer;
    C: Integer;
  end;

const
  SpecificFields: TSpecificFields =
  (A: 5; B: 4; C: 3);

procedure CallbackWrapper(GenericCallback: TGenericCallback<TSpecificFields>);

implementation

procedure CallbackWrapper(GenericCallback: TGenericCallback<TSpecificFields>);
begin
  GenericCallback(SpecificFields);
end;

procedure OnCallbackWrapper(const Fields: TSpecificFields);
begin
  Assert(Fields.A = 5);
  Assert(Fields.B = 4);
  Assert(Fields.C = 3);
end;

procedure Dummy;
begin
  CallbackWrapper(OnCallbackWrapper); //Incompatible types here
end;

end.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
procedure OnCallbackWrapper( Fields: TSpecificFields);
begin
  Assert(Fields.A = 5);
  Assert(Fields.B = 4);
  Assert(Fields.C = 3);
end;
```

or change declaration to

```
  TGenericCallback<T> = procedure(const Fields: T);
```

A procedure passing parameters by value is not assignment compatible with a procedure which passes parameters  by reference. [Reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29)

Comment: I'd up vote this if it explained why you'd need to make these changes. Btw, I understand that writing explanations in English may not be easy for you, but I'd prefer any explanation, no matter how poor the English, over no explanation at all. And: the more you practice, the better you get :-)

Comment: Besides my English problems
, I feel it is inflated obvious things to explain at length.
This is a personal problem of a rather taciturn man. I will try to adapt, but it doesn't suit my personality.

Comment: I can relate to that. It would be great if you could. Mind you, I honestely am not expecting lengthy discussions. Just some hints that help people understand your answers (which are pretty spot on). With this answer for example, having no explanation forces people to look for the differences. The edit you made really helps! Also: don't be afraid of making English mistakes. Plenty of people here willing and able to edit your answers to make the English better.

Answer (score 8):

The type that you declared receives its parameter by value.

```
TGenericCallback<T> = procedure(Fields: T); // no const
```

The function you pass is marked with `const`.

```
procedure OnCallbackWrapper(const Fields: TSpecificFields); // const parameter
```

So the compiler rejects the parameter you attempt to pass as not matching. You need to make both sides match. For example:

```
TGenericCallback<T> = procedure(const Fields: T);
```

Comment: You guys are fast:) I knew I've overlooked something. Both answers are helpful so +1 for David and answer for bummi cause he was first.

Comment: You should accept the best answer. And you should upvote bummi's too if you think it is helpful. Don't be shy. But above all, it's not just about who is the quickest. And note I'm not saying my answer is the one you should accept. I've said this many times. Accept the best answer. If someone comes along with a better answer. Accept that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Was thinking about the quality of both of your answers. The thing is that for me bummi's code was enough to understand where I've made a mistake.

Comment: Obviously it's up to you. I just took "cause he was first" at face value.

Comment: For what it's worth I do appreciate your well documented answer and I've noticed that his is a bit clumsy. That is why I did not upvoted it but marked it as an accepted answer - because it answered my question, nothing more. In that particular moment I nedeed an answer fast(I've already wasted 20 minutes or so trying to understand why my code is not compiling :) That was my exact way of thinking back then. I hope that this will not disencourage you from giving high quality answers in the future:) I do appreciate them, I mean it.

Comment: To be fair to bummi, I think English is not his first language. So it's not as easy for him to write explanations as it is for those, like me, that have English as their mother tongue. It's not remotely a problem. I just have my personal crusade for accepting the best answers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: While I agree with that sentiment, I'd prefer any explanation no matter how poor the English might be over no explanation at all.